# Различие размеров контролов Windows Form и готового приложения

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть приложение C# Windows Form. На нем лежит кнопка. В дизайнере форм размер кнопки - 40x40. Но при запуске размеры кнопки меняются(под отладкой 32 и 30). Дело в dpi, судя по всему. Как настроить это дело верно? В форме AutoScaleMode выставлял различные значения, но 40x40 так и не получил. Версия Windows: 10. Спасибо.

Comment: `AutoSize=false`

Comment: @DigitalCore включенный `AutoSize` применяется сразу, уже в дизайнере.

Comment: Кнопка лежит просто на форме или в каком-то еще контейнере поверх формы? Попробуйте зафиксировать ее размер, установив свойства `MaxSize` и `MinSize` равными свойству `Size`, это поможет исключить автоматическую коррекцию размера независимо от значений свойств, которые за нее так или иначе отвечают. Если проблема действительно в настройках DPI, отличных от дефолтных, то в WinForms вы с этим ни чего не сделаете, это известная проблема и она не лечится, в WPF такой проблемы нет.

Comment: @DigitalCore стоит.

Comment: @rdorn и даже в настройках самой Windows ничего не изменит ситуации? P.S.: испробовал Ваш совет - увы, не помог

Comment: @rdorn кнопка лежит поверх формы

Comment: @Range это чистый .Net или подключен Freamework (made in Nicaragua) ?

Comment: Не верю, что в течении 4 часов проект не сохранялся, но всё может быть ->>Сборка->> Пресобрать Решение --| конечно если элемент не создан как пользовательский в WPF

Comment: @DigitalCore установлено. Это не решило проблему. Проблему решило изменение размера шрифта Windows с 125% на 100%(ОС Win 10 по умолчанию увеличивает шрифт). Теперь я вижу реальные размеры компонент.

Comment: @DigitalCore .NET

Comment: @Range стоит оформить ответ

Comment: @Range собственно об этом я и писал про проблемы с настройкой DPI, правда не знал, что в Win10 по дефолту не 100%, спасибо. Стоит добавить в вопрос версию ОС.

Comment: По моему в 10ке скейл шрифта зависит от разришения. На 2к у меня был 100%, запускал на 4к - толи 75% то ли 50%, точно не помню

Comment: См. [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229605%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Также смотрите [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контролы WinForms реализованы как оболочка над оригинальным WinAPI и нормально работают только в формате 96 dpi (в современных интерфейсах Widows соответствует 100% размеру шрифта). Если величина dpi отличается, появляются искажения размеров контролов, "съезжает" текст, появляются прочие мало приятные сюрпризы, вроде наложения и т.п.

В зависимости от того, как и в каком контейнере размещены контролы набор побочных эффектов меняется, иногда все почти гладко, иногда полный набор "удовольствий".

Универсального способа борьбы с подобными явлениями Microsoft не предоставили. Относительно эффективный способ - исключить фиксированное положение и размеры контролов, используя по максимуму возможности свойств `Dock`, `AutoSize` и контейнеров с динамической компоновкой контента или с возможностью задать размер контрола относительно размера контейнера.

По этой же причине, очень сложно сделать нормальную поддержку большого диапазона разрешений экранов (например от 800х600 до 1920х1080, не говоря уже про более высокие разрешения), т.к. придется в ручную ловить изменение пользовательских настроек экрана и перестраивать интерфейс с учетом нового масштаба во время выполнения.

На данный момент, если вам нужен одинаковый внешний вид, независимо от пользовательских настроек экрана, самым эффективным решением будет отказ от WinForms в пользу WPF или UWP, в которых данные проблемы отсутствуют, так как размеры задаются в независимых от параметров экрана величинах (например дюймах или процентах) и зависимость от от WinAPI и его исторических тараканов почти отсутствует (базовое окно приложению все еще предоставляет WinAPI, а вот его содержимым занимается уже DirectX, на абсолютную точность не претендую, поправьте если в чем-то ошибся).

Comment: WPF конечно решит проблему кардинально :)

Comment: @Range если готовы перейти на модель MVVM, то почему бы и нет, по части возможностей визуального оформления, WPF на порядки мощнее WinForms. По производительности может проигрывать формам, если оба варианта написаны правильно, но чаще получается наоборот, погоня за рюшечками и дикая логика в контролах полностью убивает производительность форм.

Comment: с C# знаком относительно недавно, эксперементирую так сказать..всегда на С++ писал обычно.